# i want to pass data one activity to another fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment

i have one activity and i want to pass data from activity to fragment. i have main activity which contain two fragment and one button i just click to button than my dummy data show on fragment can i possible i am many time to try but every time face same error "Binary XML file line #9: 
  Error inflating class fragment" please help me

Exception:

> Process: com.sytechnology.fragmentdata, PID: 12907
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sytechnology.fragmentdata/com.sytechnology.fragmentdata.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error
>   inflating class fragment
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
>        Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
>           at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>           at com.sytechnology.fragmentdata.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
>   android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object
>   reference
>           at com.sytechnology.fragmentdata.FragementOne.onCreateView(FragementOne.java:32)
>           at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2439)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureInflatedFragmentView(FragmentManager.java:1689)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1431)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1684)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1930)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:3745)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:120)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:405)

this code is data pass activity to fragment

```
button =findViewById(R.id.mainButtonId);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

Bundle bundle= new Bundle();

bundle.putString("demo","dummy data");

FragementOne fragementOne= new FragementOne();

fragementOne.setArguments(bundle);
       //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainFragme ntOn,fragementOne).commit();
}
});
```

this is fragment code where i receive data from activity

```
TextView textView;

public FragementOne()
{

}
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one,container,false);
    textView=(TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fregmentOneText);

        String name=this.getArguments().getString("demo");


 textView.setText(name);
 return rootView;

"Here is My XML of Fragment"


 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  


android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
android:id="@+id/mainFragmentOn"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/fregmentOneText"
android:text="fregmanetOn"
/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Here is My main Activity XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<fragment
android:layout_width="0px"
android:layout_height="300dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:name="com.sytechnology.fragmentdata.FragementOne"
android:id="@+id/fragment1"
/>
<fragment
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/fragment2"
    android:name="com.sytechnology.fragmentdata.FragmentTwo"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mainButtonId"
android:text="click"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"

        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send data from activity to fragment in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)

Comment: can you post xml file ?

Comment: please check My XML

Comment: Ashish can you please check my xml